# An alternative way to say "shifting perspectives"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What would be a good alternative way to say "shifting perspectives", as in the meaning of looking at things in a new way?

Comment: Are you sure that's what the phrase/ term means?

Comment: A positive expression would be "newer vistas."

Answer (score 1):

You could use ***paradigm shift***, specially if this new way of looking at things is very different from the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather generic, but there's always *a new point of view* or possibly even *a new outlook* or *a new frame of mind*.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the slightly more technical **gestalt shift**, used in pyschology and philosophy.

I'm not sure how authoritative a source [this is](http://undaimonia.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/gestalt-shift.html), but it says:

> In psychology, a *gestalt shift* is when your perception suddenly changes. In his Philosophical Investigations, Wittgenstein illustrated this with the duck-rabbit illusion: you can see either the duck or the rabbit but not both at the same time. Your brain switches between the two in an instant. Your perception changes. In life, there are longer term gestalt shifts: moments when your perception shifts and suddenly everything has changed. Afterwards, you see things anew and the universe clicks together in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

**transformative** would have a similar meaning to "perspective shifting"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).